# COPY data from table1 to table2 with date inserted as 7 days back or 14 days back?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv

I have a table1 which has these many columns -

```
A
B
C
```

Now I have a table2 which has these many columns

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

In table2 I have D as the `created_date` and E as the `updated_date`. Now I want to import table1 data into table2 for which I have already exported table1 data into CSV file.

Initially I have made column D and Column E as now() so while I was copying the data from table1 to table2 using `COPY command`, the date was getting inserted automatically which was the current date.

Now what I am looking for is, whenever I am copying any data from table1 to table2, `created_date` which is `D` and `updated_date` which is `E` in  above table2 should be set to `now()-interval '7 days'`.

I have already imported table1 data into CSV file as I have mentioned above and now I need to import this CSV file into table2 such that while I am inserting using COPY command, I should be able to set the created_date and updated_date to `7 days` back or `14 days` back etc..

Basically, I want this to be configurable, suppose if I am using COPY command then depending on the situation if I need to insert the data for 7 days back, then while I am copying the data, I should set that date should be 7 days back or 14 days back or 30 days back from the command line.

Is there any way I can do that? Any help would be really appreciated..

**UPDATE:-**

I forgot to mention, both of the tables are in different database. So we cannot insert basis on select query I guess..

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO [TARGET_DB].[dbo].Table2
                     (adID, CampaignName, EndDate)
SELECT        adID, [CampaignEndDate],   DATEADD(d, -14, [CampaignEndDate]) as EndDate
FROM    [SOURCE_DB].[dbo].Table1
```

replace -14 days back

if DBs are in same server use above

to update other DB different servers you do connections string

use
OPENQUERY (Transact-SQL)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx

connections OPENDATASOURCE 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention, both of the tables are in different database. So we cannot insert basis on select query I guess..

Comment: Yes you can do it<br>A. you can use SELECT INTO to build new table and add after that indexes<br> B.You can define you schema first then insert with INSERT INTO Table2  the select is from Table1 then import to the other DB; I can post you the solution in 2 hours I have it in my other PC  You can open connection to the other DB I did this before