# How to use result of query to select in to another table in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I'm new here. I have a problem selecting results of a query into another database.

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"rohanstat", "UID"=>$UID, "PWD"=>$PASS);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
$sql2 = "SET ROWCOUNT 15 SELECT   attacker, COUNT(attacker) AS dupe_cnt FROM [rohanstat].[dbo].[TPKill]
GROUP BY attacker
HAVING   COUNT(attacker) > 0
ORDER BY COUNT(attacker) DESC";
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql2);
while($rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2))
echo $rows ['attacker']."<br>";
?>
```

I just want to use `$rows['attacker']` to select in to another database. Which means I want to use it like this.

```
sql = "select * from [RohanGame].[dbo].[TCharacter] where name = $rows ['attacker'];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into the "select into" command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tags for the question are SQL; sql-server

but is same for mySQL Oracle and other DBs

here  I answer  to other question in T-SQL

You can do in PHP in two ways
read in the memory from DB1 then open connection and do your logic to DB2

or in T-SQL you can do it in one query

[COPY data from table1 to table2 with date inserted as 7 days back or 14 days back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528406/copy-data-from-table1-to-table2-with-date-inserted-as-7-days-back-or-14-days-bac/20528778#20528778)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `IN`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [RohanGame].[dbo].[TCharacter] 
WHERE   name IN 
        (   SELECT   TOP 15 attacker
            FROM [rohanstat].[dbo].[TPKill]
            GROUP BY attacker
            HAVING   COUNT(attacker) > 0
            ORDER BY COUNT(attacker) DESC
        );
```

Or if you need the COUNT you can JOIN your results together:

```
SELECT  tc.*, a.Dupe_cnt
FROM    [RohanGame].[dbo].[TCharacter]  tc
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT   TOP 15 attacker, COUNT(attacker) AS dupe_cnt 
            FROM [rohanstat].[dbo].[TPKill]
            GROUP BY attacker
            HAVING   COUNT(attacker) > 0
            ORDER BY COUNT(attacker) DESC
        ) a
            ON a.Attacker = tc.name;
```

I don't think it will make much, if any difference, but you can swap out:

```
HAVING   COUNT(attacker) > 0
```

with

```
WHERE   attacker IS NOT NULL
```

Since you are already grouping by attacker, the only group where `COUNT(attacker)` will not be null is the group where attacker is null:

```
SELECT  tc.*, a.Dupe_cnt
FROM    [RohanGame].[dbo].[TCharacter]  tc
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT   TOP 15 attacker, COUNT(*) AS dupe_cnt 
            FROM [rohanstat].[dbo].[TPKill]
            WHERE attacker IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY attacker
            ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        ) a
            ON a.Attacker = tc.name;
```

Comment: Finally i got it. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to sort it from dupe_cnt?

Comment: Yes, use the query with `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN`, and simply add `ORDER BY a.dupe_cnt`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution using PHP as well, namely the `$rows` variable you've declared, you could so something similar to this:

```php
$attackers = "";
foreach($rows as $row) {
  $attackers .= "$row,";
}
//Get rid of the last comma
$attackers = rtrim($attackers, ',');
$sql = sprintf("select * from [RohanGame].[dbo].[TCharacter] where name IN (%s)", $attackers);
```